# PermissionError when copying files using shutil.copyfile

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and this is my first application.
So, basically, the application takes a folder with mp3 files in it, and reads the metadata for artist name, and then sorts the songs accordingly by copying them into newly created sub-folders named after the artist name. If there's no artist name, it would create a folder called 'unsorted' and copy files into that. I have got to the point of being able to create new folders, but the last bit which is copying the files gives me a PermissionError. Below are the code and the error I am getting.

```
import os
import eyed3
import shutil

# get the path to music directory
musicFolder = input('please enter the full path of your music folder : ')
correctedPath = musicFolder.replace('/', '//')

musicList = []

# list of audio file objects
for _files in os.listdir(correctedPath):
    if _files.endswith('.mp3'):
        musicList.append(eyed3.load(correctedPath + '//' + _files))

sortedFolder = ''

# check tag info for album artist, and sort to folders
for _audioFiles in musicList:
    if _audioFiles.tag.album_artist != None:
        sortedFolder = correctedPath + '//' + _audioFiles.tag.album_artist
    else:
        sortedFolder = correctedPath + '//' + 'Unsorted'
    if not os.path.exists(sortedFolder):
        os.mkdir(sortedFolder)
    shutil.copyfile(_audioFiles.path, sortedFolder)
```

Error
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C://Users//Manu//Music//Music Test//Coldplay'

Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would make sure that you have read + write permissions on the newly created folder. Something like this https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line might be helpful. It is likely that you don't have permission to write to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using forward slash / where you should be using backslash .

```
'C://Users//Manu//Music//Music Test//Coldplay'
```

should be

```
'C:\\Users\\Manu\\Music\\Music Test\\Coldplay'
```

Better yet, Python has built in libraries to assist with paths:  os.path and pathlib.

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f

Comment: thanks for the reply. it didn't make a difference. infact, the reason i used forward slash was I thought that was the escape character (silly mistake). I changed all of them to backslash. But that was not the issue. it still creates the folders based on the artist names if i comment out the shutil part. As soon as I uncomment it, it creates the first folder but is not able to copy the file into the folder. That's when it errors out. But yeah, am still wondering why backslash and forwardslash isn't making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

shutil.copy2(src,dst) fixed it for me. I changed it from shutil.copyfile.

[shutil copy functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcnlE.png)